# Layer Preview not showing published layers

Tags: geoserver

I have a Geoserver instance in which i published layers, The layer preview does list the available layers only when i'm logged in but it does not list them on the logged off layer preview page. How can i make the layers available publicly even if you are not logged on?

[image: Logged In & Logged off layer preview]

Comment: did you set up any security rules? if so unset them

Comment: all the security roles allow access to all roles including anonymous users

Comment: pretty sure they don't or you would see the layers when not logged in as that is the default

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem today and found the issue. Log into your admin console and click on GeoFence Data Rules.

[image: GeoFence Data Rules]

I'm going to guess that you don't have any rules set to allow anonymous access to your workspace.

[image: Permissive anonymous access]

In my case I needed to set a rule to allow anonymous access to the specific workspace. You can also set it to allow access to all `*` workspaces, but I wouldn't recommend that.

I should mention I'm running 2.18 so YMMV.

More info from the [manual's section on GeoFence here](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/extensions/geofence/configuration.html).